# Is it possible to cache a file in the browser despite its querystring?

Tags: browser

Is it possible to cache a file in the browser regardless of its query string parameters?

For instance loading the same cached assets for both:

```
https://example.com?value=foo
https://example.com?value=bar
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's part of the options available to the [Cache's `.match(request, options)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache/match) method: `ignoreSearch`.

So when checking your Cache, set this option to true and both requests will be treated the same.