# Is it possible to force a browser to use the same cache entry for different paths?

Tags: path, browser-cache, cache-control

For example, there are 2 paths at the same domain: `some_domain.com/first` and `some_domain.com/second`.

Both of these paths return the same file, let's say - `contents.html`. Is it possible to configure caches in the way that after opening `some_domain.com/first` no loading will be performed for `some_domain.com/second` - so it will just reuse the cache prepared for `some_domain.com/first`?

Should it be done server-side by returning some special hypothetical `Cache-Key: key_value` header? The closest related thing could find is this question:
[Is it possible to cache a file in the browser despite its querystring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63044884/is-it-possible-to-cache-a-file-in-the-browser-despite-its-querystring)

Update - I can rephrase it a little bit. I'm using React with its Router. The server is configured to return `index.html` for all possible paths allowing then to process routes by client-side JS. Let's say, there is some caching configured to prevent everything the server returns from being expired. But here is an issue. Once I open `some_domain.com/first`, it gets cached, so the next time I access the same path, it is not downloaded again. But even if `some_domain.com/second` returns the same `index.html`, it's not cached after `some_domain.com/first` had been opened - I need to open this second path as well (i.e. by reloading the corresponding page in browser) at least once to make it cached as well (while it's obviously pointless, as both routes return the same `index.html`).

Comment: The closest thing I can find is a service worker configuration. There are even out-of-the-box templates for React and some webpack plugins. But it seems a little bit an overkill: I just want to prevent those rare cases when routes are accessed not by React's Router (not navigated to by `Link`s - to be more accurate) but with a direct link from loading `index.html` again (until its cache is not expired).

Comment: Similar, but unanswered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60985488/http-cache-multiple-urls-point-to-the-same-html-file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I deal with different requests that map to the same response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744975/how-do-i-deal-with-different-requests-that-map-to-the-same-response)

Comment: The accepted answer from the link suggests to redirect routes to their duplicated versions, if got it right. In other words, if I request `some_domain.com/second`, it should be redirected to `some_domain.com/first` which has already some cache saved. But there is at least one issue: React app will process `some_domain.com/first` instead of `some_domain.com/second` to render contents as the URL being parsed client-side gets changed (so the wrong page will be rendered). So this doesn't answer my question.